# Why is my Nearley grammar causing a loop?

Tags: nearley

I am playing around with nearley.js and something is confusing me.
As a test I am trying to build a parser parsing poker ranks.

Now, this grammar is working as expected:

```
@{% function nuller() { return null; } %}

main -> _ composition _                         {% nuller %}

composition -> _ expression _                   {% nuller %}
    | composition _ "," _ rank                  {% nuller %}

expression -> _ rank _                          {% nuller %}
rank -> [a, k, q, j, t, A, K, Q, J, T, 2-9]     {% nuller %}

_ -> [\s]:*                                     {% nuller %}
```

However, the second I change `| composition _ "," _ rank` to `| composition _ "," _ expression` then I end up with a loop:

```
@{% function nuller() { return null; } %}

main -> _ composition _                         {% nuller %}

composition -> _ expression _                   {% nuller %}
    | composition _ "," _ expression            {% nuller %}

expression -> _ rank _                          {% nuller %}
rank -> [a, k, q, j, t, A, K, Q, J, T, 2-9]     {% nuller %}

_ -> [\s]:*                                     {% nuller %}
```

Can somebody explain me why that is? 
Code can quickly be tested at the playground:
https://omrelli.ug/nearley-playground/

The test string I use is: `a, k, q, j, t, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2`

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are multiple interpretations possible for each of the values in your string, this is because you both have optional whitespace before your expression and rank:

If you look at the second element `k`, this can be interpreted as:

- space + expression
- space + rank

Since you have 2 possibilities for 12 items in your string, you will get 144 possible combinations.

This returns one solution (i have left out the optional whitespace before `expression`):

```
main -> _ composition _                         {% nuller %}

composition -> _ expression _                   {% nuller %}
    | composition _ "," expression              {% nuller %}

expression -> _ rank _                          {% nuller %}
rank -> [a, k, q, j, t, A, K, Q, J, T, 2-9]     {% nuller %}

_ -> [\s]:*                                     {% nuller %}
```